# Critical Timing in an ARM Linux Kernel Driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, arm, driver

I am running linux on an MX28 (ARMv5), and am using a GPIO line to talk to a device.  Unfortunately, the device has some special timing requirements.  A low on the GPIO line cannot last longer than 7us, highs have no special timing requirements.  The code is implemented as a kernel device driver, and toggles the GPIO with direct register writes rather than going through the kernel GPIO api.  For testing, I am just generating 3 pulses.  The process is as follows, all in one function so it should fit in the instruction cache:

- set gpio high
- Save Flags & Disable Interrupts
- gpio low
- pause
- gpio high
- repeat 2x more
- Restore Flags/Reenable Interrups

Here's the output of a logic analyzer tied to the GPIO.

[image: Picture of three pulses]

Most of the time it works just great, and the pulses last just under 1us.  However, about 10% of the lows last for many, many microseconds. Even though interrupts are disabled, something is causing the flow of the code to be interrupted.

[image: Weird long pulse]

I am at a loss.  RT Linux would likely not help here, because the problem is not latency, it appears to be something happening during the low, even though nothing should interrupt it with the IRQs disabled.  Any suggestions would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there some additional core or functional unit (DMA, etc) which could be claiming the bus?  If the system runs something such as uboot, could you try building code into that as a comparison test, or doing it in pure assembly very early in kernel startup before much is initialized?

Comment: I don't believe so.  The GPIOs are dedicated.  This looks like the cpu stops executing the code for a little while.  What I suspect is happening is a page-fault or something of the kind.  I tried adding a barrier to the start of it, just in case there was some issue with out-of-order execution, but it didn't change anything.  U-Boot is acting as the boot loader, and most of the code I'm executing now is already assembler, so I probably could add a command to u-boot to exercise this.

Comment: @Arcane: If you had a page fault with interrupts disabled, things would not pause -- they would break.  Horribly.  What Chris is discussing (multiple bus masters on the main memory bus) would cause the core to pause execution (in the "fetch" phase of fetch-decode-execute) until the other bus transaction was complete.  For example, a display controller often has priority because late reads from the framebuffer will cause a corrupted display.

Comment: Smart use of the instruction cache might prevent the need to load code across the main memory bus.

Comment: It might not even be competition with another bus master, it could merely be a cache miss.  What clockspeed and CAS latency does your DRAM use?

Comment: @BenVoigt - even beyond instruction fetches, access to the GPIO block may go over an internal bus where there is arbitration with other cores/engines.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, good point.

Comment: Looking at the block diagram for the SoC, the GPIO block is connected via a shared bus.   The RAM is 333Mhz, CL5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ARM *cache* on an IMX25 (ARM926) is 16K Code, 16K Data L1  with a 32byte length or eight instructions.  With the DDR-SDRAM controller running at 133Mhz and a 16bit bus the transfer rate is about 300MB/s.  A cache fill should only take about 100nS, not 9uS; this is about 100 times too long.

However, you have four other issues with Linux.

1. TLB misses and a page table walk.
2. Data aborts.
3. DMA masters stealing.
4. FIQ interrupts.

It is unlikely that the LCD master is stealing enough bandwidth, unless you have a huge display.  Is your display larger than 1/4VGA?  If not, this is only 10% of the memory bandwidth and this will pipeline with the processor.  Do you have either Ethernet or USB active?  These peripherals are higher data rate and could cause this type of contention with SDRAM.

All of these issues maybe avoided by writing your toggler PC relative and copying it to the IRAM.  See: [iram_alloc.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/mach-imx/iram_alloc.c); this file should be portable to older versions of Linux.  The XBAR switch allows fetches from SDRAM and IRAM simultaneously.  The *IRAM* can still be a target of other *DMA* masters.  If you are really pressed, move the code to the *ETB* buffers which no other master in the system can access.

The *TLB miss* can actually be quite steep as it may need to run several *single beat* SDRAM cycles; still this should be under 1uS.  You have not posted code, so it is possible that a variable and/or other is causing a *data fault* which is not maskable.

If you have any drivers using the *FIQ*, they may still be running even though you have masked the normal *IRQ* interrupts.  For instance, the **ALSA** driver for this system normally uses the *FIQ*.

Both the *ETB* and the *IRAM* are 32-bit data paths and low wait state.  Either one will probably give better response than the DDR-SDRAM.

We have achieved sub micro-second response by using a *FIQ* and *IRAM* to toggle GPIOs on an IMX258 with another protocol using bit banging.

Comment: Ask you **FAE** for the *internal buses PDF*.  It will help to show what memory/peripherals will cause contention for your system configuration.  Ie, it is a diagram of DMA masters and slaves connections.

Comment: No display on this hardware, but it does have both ethernet and USB actively working.

Answer (score 3):

One possible workaround to the problem Chris mentioned (in addition to problems with paging of kernel module code) is to use a PWM peripheral where the duration of the pulse is pre-programmed and the timing is implemented in hardware.

Fancy processors with caches are not suitable for hard realtime work.  Execution time varies if cache misses are non-deterministic (and designs where cache misses are completely deterministic aren't complicated enough to justify a fancy processor).

You can try to avoid memory controller latency during critical sections by aligning the critical section so that it doesn't straddle cache lines.  Or prefetch the code you will need.  But this is going to be very non-portable and create a nightmare for future maintenance.  And still doesn't protect the access to memory-mapped GPIO from bus contention.

Comment: I have a fallback of using the PWM.  However, there are other factors with this protocol (spy-bi-wire) that require me to read from a line while the gpio is pulled low, so I still have the timing critical issue.

Comment: @Arcane: For that you can just add an external D flip-flop to enregister the line you're reading from and clock it from the GPIO we're discussing.  Whatever value was on the data line immediately prior to the rising edge of your control line will be latched.