# Interrupt performance on linux kernel with RT patches - should be better?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I have bumped into a bit inconsistent IRQ/ISR performance on Freescales imx.233 running  linux kernel (3.8.13) with CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT patches. 
I am little bit surprised why this processor (ARM9, 454mhz) is unable to keep up even with 74kHz IRQ requests.. ?

In my kernel config I have set following flags:

```
CONFIG_TINY_PREEMPT_RCU=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_BASE=y
CONFIG_HAVE_PREEMPT_LAZY=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_LAZY=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_COUNT=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_PREEMPT=y
```

On the system there is basically nothing running (created by buildroot), and I set PWM to generate a pulse of 74kHz, that serves as interrupt.
Then in the ISR, I just trigger another GPIO output pin, and check the output.
What I find is that sometimes I miss an interrupt -
You can see the missed interrupt here:

[image: missed interrupt]

And also the the triggering of output pin seems to be a bit inconsistent, the output pin is triggered usually within "5% window", that might still be acceptable. But I worry, that when I start implementing data transfer logic, instead of just triggering the pin, I might run into further problems...

My simple driver code looks like this:

```
#needed includes

uint16_t INPUT_IRQ = 39;
uint16_t OUTPUT_GPIO = 38;

struct test_device *device;

//Prototypes
void irqtest_exit(void);
int irqtest_init(void);
void free_device(void);

//Default functions
module_init(irqtest_init);
module_exit(irqtest_exit);

//triggering flag
uint16_t pulse = 0x1;

irqreturn_t irq_handle_function(int irq, void *device_id)
{
pulse = !pulse;
gpio_set_value(OUTPUT_GPIO, pulse);

return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

struct test_device { 
    int huuhaa;
};

void free_device() {
if (device)
    kfree(device);
}   

int irqtest_init(void) {
    int result = 0;

    device = kmalloc(sizeof *device, GFP_KERNEL);
    device->huuhaa = 10;

    printk("IRB/irqtest_init: Inserting IRQ module\n"); 

    printk("IRB/irqtest_init: Requesting GPIO (%d)\n", INPUT_IRQ); 
    result = gpio_request_one(INPUT_IRQ, GPIOF_IN, "PWM input");

    if (result != 0) {
        free_device();
        printk("IRB/irqtest_init: Failed to set GPIO (%d) as input.. exiting\n", INPUT_IRQ);
        return -EINVAL;
    } 
    result = gpio_request_one(OUTPUT_GPIO, GPIOF_OUT_INIT_LOW , "IR OUTPUT");
    if (result != 0) {
        free_device();
        printk("IRB/irqtest_init: Failed to set GPIO (%d) as output.. exiting\n", OUTPUT_GPIO);
        return -EINVAL;
    } 

    //Set our desired interrupt line as input
    result = gpio_direction_input(INPUT_IRQ);

    if (result != 0) {
        printk("IRB/irqtest_init: Failed to set IRQ as input.. exiting\n");
        free_device();
        return -EINVAL;
    }   

    //Set flags for our interrupt, guessing here..
    irq_flags |=  IRQF_NO_THREAD;
    irq_flags |=  IRQF_NOBALANCING;
    irq_flags |=  IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING;
    irq_flags |=  IRQF_NO_SOFTIRQ_CALL;

    //register interrupt
    result = request_irq(gpio_to_irq(INPUT_IRQ), irq_handle_function, irq_flags, "irq testing", device);

    if (result != 0) {
        printk("IRB/irqtest_init: Failed to reserve GPIO 38\n");
        return -EINVAL;
    } 
    printk("IRB/irqtest_init: insert success\n"); 
    return 0;
}

void irqtest_exit(void) {
    if (device)
        kfree(device);
    gpio_free(INPUT_IRQ);
    gpio_free(OUTPUT_GPIO);

    printk("IRB/irqtest_exit: Removing irqtest module\n");
}


int irqtest_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {return 0;}
int irqtest_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {return 0;}
```

In the system, I have following interrupts registered, after the driver is loaded:

```
# cat /proc/interrupts 
       CPU0       
 16:      36379         -  MXS Timer Tick
 17:          0         -  mxs-spi
 18:       2103         -  mxs-dma
 60:          0  gpio-mxs  irq testing
118:          0         -  mxs-spi
119:          0         -  mxs-dma
120:          0         -  RTC alarm
124:          0         -  8006c000.serial
127:      68050         -  uart-pl011
128:        151         -  ci13xxx_imx
Err:          0
```

I wonder if the flags I declare to my IRQ are good ? I noticed that with this configuration, I can no longer reach console, so kernel seems totally consumed with servicing this 74kHz trigger now.. this can't be right ? 
I suppose it's not a big deal for me since this is only during data transfer, but still I feel I'm doing something wrong..

Also, I wonder if it would be more efficient to map the registers with ioremap, and trigger the output with direct memory writes ?

Is there some way I could increase the priority of the interrupt even higher ? Or could I somehow lock the kernel for the duration of the data transfer (~400ms), and generate somehow else my timing for the output ?

Edit: Forgot to add /proc/interrupts output to the question...

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115082/critical-timing-in-an-arm-linux-kernel-driver) as it might be of interest.

Comment: @artlessnoise Thanks for your reply. This indeed looked interesting, but I can't seem to import this mxc_set_irq_fiq.. (compiler warns that it mxc_set_irq_fiq is undefined, even though I imported asoc-imx-ssi.h), and module fails to load..
The another question you referenced, he also seemed to use direct register writes, maybe I should also avoid the general GPIO library..

Comment: These symbols are exported in [irq-common.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/mach-imx/irq-common.c?id=refs/tags/v3.8.13).  Just declare `extern int mxc_set_irq_fiq(unsigned int irq, unsigned int type);` or `extern int imx_irq_set_priority(unsigned char irq, unsigned char prio);` and use them.  It looks like the `imx_irq_set_priority()` is exposed and it is an easy change to bump your *IRQ* with this.  Make sure to set **MXC_IRQ_PRIOR** in your kernel *.config*.

Comment: I would use the GPIO library as other drivers/module may modify the pins.  You can have races if you don't.  Ie, one driver sets GPIO2-3 while another is clearing GPIO2-5 and another is setting GPIO2-17.  If you know only your driver can can use all active GPIO in that group, then you can use it directly.

Comment: @artlessnoise When I changed my platform from MXS to MXC, I was no longer able to boot the kernel (it hung already in u-boot trying to load the kernel, even "uncompressing linux" wasn't shown), I guess some configurations for mx23 went wrong..
I copied irqcommon.c and .h from mach-imx to mach-mxs, built, and then I was able to compile the driver against it, but calling `mxc_set_irq_fiq(INPUT_IRQ,1);` returns -38.. I am trying to call it after I registered the IRQ

Comment: @artlessnoise maybe this is very silly question, but I was looking at `arch/arm/mach-imx/avic.c` (I see they are directly writing into registers) and also trying to re-read once again the reference manual for mx23, it states `On i.MX23, all interrupt sources can be configured as FIQ. This is controlled via the
HW_ICOLL_INTERRUPTn[ENFIQ] register bit` (p.114). What if I would set the ENFIQ bit in HW_ICOLL_INTERRUPT17 (vector: 0x0044 - GPIO bank 1 interrupt).. would that make my registered GPIO line go through FIQ?

Comment: Yes, of course you can write directly.  Currently there is no interaction with Linux, but at some point these features maybe integrated; I guess the name will change from `mxc_set_irq_fiq()` to `arm_set_irq_fiq()`, if they were generically supported.  Note when operating in **FIQ** mode, the kernel facilities you can use are very limited. Only [registers can be read](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/fiqasm.S?id=refs/tags/v3.8.13) or use of `swp`.

Comment: For your time scale, the *FIQ* by itself should be fine.   However, you do still have other *BUS masters* that can steal memory cycles, so you will get some jitter as explained in the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115082/critical-timing-in-an-arm-linux-kernel-driver).  The priority should give a similar response to the *FIQ* and allow the use of kernel facilities.

Comment: @artlessnoise Sorry for my late reply (GMT+9), I tried setting the register directly (and re-reading the register, it seemed to be correct), but after that I no longer get any output triggering (the irq function isn't called?). Regarding **FIQ**, if I would be limited only to registers and swap, how would one take care of the actual data to be transferred (it originally comes from user space). Maybe `imx_irq_set_priority()` is what I should concentrate on, but calling that function seems to lock up the driver loading as well.. any chance I could ask more advice via email? (mine is in profile)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you experience here is interrupt jitter. This is to be expected on Linux, because the kernel regularly disables the interrupts for various tasks (entering a spinlock, handling an interrupt, etc.).

This will happen, regardless wether you have PREEMPT_RT or not, so expecting to generate 74kHz signal with regular interrupts is pretty much unrealistic.

Now, ARM has higher priority interrupts called FIQs, that will never be masked or disabled.

Linux doesn't use FIQ, and is not built to deal with the fact that an FIQ could be used, so you won't be able to use the generic kernel framework.

From Linux driver development point of view however, it's not really different as long as you keep this in mind: you have to write a handler, and associate it to an IRQ. You'll also have to poke into the interrupt controller to make it generate a FIQ for the interrupt you want to use (the details on how to change it are platform-dependant. Some platforms have functions to do that (like imx25 and mxc_set_irq_fiq), some others don't. imx23/28 don't, so you'll have to do it by hand).

The only thing that the functions to setup a fiq handler only work with a assembly-written handler, so you'll have to rewrite your handler in assembly (with your current code, it should be trivial though).

You can grab additional details to the blog post Alexandre posted (http://free-electrons.com/blog/fiq-handlers-in-the-arm-linux-kernel/), where you'll find working code, samples, and explanations on how it all works together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and thanks for explaining my misunderstanding about PREEMPT_RT patches.
I cloned to the cfa10049 tree, and I'm trying to understand the driver there. 
Your approach on using a timer is also very interesting, maybe I will consider same approach, as PWM needs more calculations by the looks of the timer code.

Comment: I managed to successfully confirm this to work now on mx23 also. Thanks again for your great blog post!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at what my colleague Maxime Ripard did using an FIQ on a similar SoC (i.mx28) :

http://free-electrons.com/blog/fiq-handlers-in-the-arm-linux-kernel/

Comment: Alexandre, thanks for the link! It's interesting to see how similar his output in Saleae is when using normal IRQ:s, I guess he is running into exactly same issue!
However, I'm still new these linux drivers, and I can't seem to understand how I could implement this in my driver.. In this example your colleague is using user land application, am I correct ? And he wrote the code in assembler ? Is there some complete example ? Can I selfishly ask you to ask him to comment on this question here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this flags:

```
int irq_flags;
...
irq_flags = IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING | IRQF_EARLY_RESUME
```

I had a kernel 3.8.11 and can't find IRQF_NO_SOFTIRQ_CALL define. It's only for 3.8.13?
Also I didn't see irq_flags define. Where is it?

Comment: thanks for your reply. That define comes with the CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT patch set.
I tried suggested flags, and unfortunately I have same results as before... I think maybe somehow getting those FIQ interrupts running might be the key here, as Alexandre Belloni points out below.. So far no luck, though