# How to disable an interruption in kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm working on a project which includes an imx28 from freescale and linux 2.6.35. To communicate with an external peripheral (EXAR xr20m1280), I need to write a kernel driver which use the SPI bus.

This component is a bridge SPI <-> fast UART (16Mbit/s) and the difficulty in the development of the driver is to read the data enough fast to avoid overwriting. During the test I saw some issues because an interruption is process when I read the data.

I know that it's not a good idea to disable an interruption but I don't find another solution. But to program this with the most elegant way, I have some questions :

- is it the best way to use disable_irq() and enable_irq() ? I tryed
  spinlock_irqsave() but that crashs the system.
- is there a structure (or something like that) in kernel space where I can read all the enabled interruptions ?
- If not, is there a solution to create a generic driver (without the number of the interruption in the driver code) ?

Comment: You may consider a [*FIQ*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973933/what-is-the-difference-between-fiq-and-irq-interrupt-system), [Accessing FIQ data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690715/accessing-kernel-driver-data-from-fiq-interrupt-handler-failing), [Critical timing on imx28](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115082/critical-timing-in-an-arm-linux-kernel-driver).  The **ARM** has a global enable.  See `arch_local_irq_enable` and `arch_local_irq_disable` in in [*irqflag.h*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/irqflags.h#n73).

Comment: *"...read the data enough fast to avoid **overwriting**"* -- Don't you mean "overrun"?  "Read" and "write" operations are usually from the the perspective of the CPU.  Are you using PIO to read the SPI data?  Have you tried DMA chaining?

Comment: @sawdust DMA is not supported in 2.6.35; you need at least 3.0+ to get the SDMA support.  I think [Sascha Hauer wrote it](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/1/9/85).  I guess he can try to port the patches.